# как восстановить удаленные записи из БД?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Я случайно удалил записи из одной таблицы в базе. Как можно восстановить если не было резервных копий? Heroku Postgresql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472318/can-i-rollback-a-transaction-ive-already-committed-data-loss

Comment: Раз не было бекапа - значит и данные были не нужны. К датафайлам доступа так понимаю нет, т.е. приёмы прикладной некромантии не применимы.

Comment: @norbornen важная деталь -- Heroku. Кроме доступа клиентом постгреса никакого доступа к серверу СУБД там не дают. Это эдакий DBaaS.

Comment: @D-side, сорян, не знал, что это важно

Comment: @D-side если написать в поддержку?

Comment: у вас база на VPS стоит? Если да, то хостер ничего и не сможет бекапить, окромя снапшотов самого инстанса, но это обычно за доп деньги. Вообщем, вероятность, что вы что-то восстановите крайне мала.

Comment: @tcpack4 я сессию не закрыл и удаленные все данные у меня есть. я скопировал поля. можно ли как то попробовать самому?

Comment: и данные удалены только из одной таблицы

Comment: в каком виде эти скопированные поля, сколько данных было удалено?

Comment: @tcpack4 массив из вот таких записей `#<User id: 79, first_name: "a" ...`

Comment: @tcpack4 это Heroku, никаких VPS.

Comment: Восстановил. Всем спасибо. При удалении в консоли хероку отображаются все пользователи которых удалил. Благо додумался скопировать и занести в файл. Снял дамп с базы, накатил локально и локально занес этих пользователей в базу, затем локальную базу накатил на сервер. Слава Богу, обошлось. чуть не облысел сегодня.